# Displaying two parameters from database that need to be paired together in a list under the common name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a ban list database system that holds the Rule type(*category*) and then a specific rule for it.

I have multiple rules with the same rule type name, but I cannot figure out how to make my website display both sets of rules for the category, underneath the  Name header of the rule type.

Example: I have two categories:

1. Ban rules.
2. Conduct rules.

but my ban rules has 2 rows in my database and  I cannot figure out how to display them both in a list format underneath the title "Ban Rules".

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM minecraft";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-lg-12'>";
    echo "<ul style='background-color:transparent;' class='list-group-item'>";
    echo "Rules:";
    echo "</ul>";
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-lg-12'>";
    echo "<li style='background-color:transparent;' class='list-group-item'>";
    echo $row['rule_type'];
    echo "</li>";
            //I need this one to produce two results underneath the 'Rule Type header on my list, but it only gives me one of the two results i need!//'
    echo "<li style='background-color:transparent;' class='list-group-item'>";
    echo  $row['rule'];
    $row['rule'](2);
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would translate the query result into a format that was easier to output and then loop over that to generate the html structure that you want. Something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM minecraft";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rules = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $type = $row['rule_type']
    $rules[$type][] = $row['rule'];
  }
}

if(!empty($rules)) {
  // outout html that precedes the list of rules

  foreach($rules as $type => $rule_names) {
    // output the html for each rule group

    foreach($rule_names as $rule_name) {
      // output the html for each rule
    }
  }
}
```